# An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, asp.net-core, logging

I have created a web application in .Net core 3.1 and trying to access DB using EF Core.
While accessing it, I am getting below error. Strangely, it was working before and nothing have changed on application side.

```
       at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.ThrowLoggingError(List`1 exceptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<Define>g__Log|0(ILogger logger, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<Define>b__1(ILogger logger, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.EventDefinition`3.Log[TLoggerCategory](IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, WarningBehavior warningBehavior, TParam1 arg1, TParam2 arg2, TParam3 arg3, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.CoreLoggerExtensions.QueryIterationFailed(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, Type contextType, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Comment: Does it work if you reboot your machine?

Comment: @mjwills: Not working anymore.

Comment: I have the same problem, but its begin after a power break. 

`An error occurred while migrating or initializing the database.
System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (1722): El servidor RPC no está disponible.`

Comment: Was any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

try to start Windows Event Log Server[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmQJY.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30125631)