# Not able to start asp .net core API due to System.AggregateException exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

After a computer restart, I am not able to start my asp .net core web API. Everything worked perfectly fine, but after the restart I get the following exception.

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'http://localhost:64616/'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (1722): The RPC server is unavailable.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite(String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID, UInt16 category, EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[] rawData, String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance, Byte[] data, Object[] values)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance, Object[] values)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.WindowsEventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.WriteMessage(String message, EventLogEntryType eventLogEntryType, Int32 eventId)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.<Log>g__LoggerLog|12_0[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, ILogger logger, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter, List`1& exceptions, TState& state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.ThrowLoggingError(List`1 exceptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.KestrelTrace.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.Log(ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception, String message, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogWarning(ILogger logger, String message, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.OverrideWithEndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I am using Kestrel to specify my server and port.
My Porgram.cs looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace InternalToolsGeneralAPI
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(
                context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
            }).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            }).UseWindowsService();

    }
}
```

My appSettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
      }
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And my launchSettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:23061",
      "sslPort": 44333
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "InternalToolsGeneralAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64616/"
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea how can I resolve this issue, I've tried everything and nothing worked so far.

Comment: Please copy the complete exception into the question as text. It's inherently text, and is the core of the question - having to click through to an image (which we can't copy/paste from, etc) makes it harder to help you.

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66574101. There was a suggestion there to check that the Windows Event Log service was started - could you check that?

Comment: Yes, I checked and the result is this: "Event Log service is unavauilable. Verify that the service is running." It is not able to start for some reason.

Comment: When I try to start the service, I get the following error: Windows could not start the Windows Event Log service on Local Computer. Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions on this PC?

Comment: maybe this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/fail-write-event-log can help you

Comment: Sounds like potentially you need to reinstall Windows - or find some other way to repair the Event Log. Either way, it's not really about ASP.NET Core any more.

Comment: I have found the problem, it was due to the fact that I had missing registry keys. The missing key was Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Parameters and after I added it, the Event Log was able to start, and also my API was able to run. Thanks everyone.