# Failed Executing DbCommand during Entity Framework migration in .NetCORE Web API --

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-migrations

I created a .netcore webapi targeting framework 3.1. Added the required classes and code in ApplicationUser and ApplicationDbContext and in startup services.AddDbContext<..........

Then I ran command add-migration IniCr which built and ran ok.
But when I ran the update-database console window shows the following error:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (21ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [AspNetUsers] (
          [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
          [UserName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
          [NormalizedUserName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
          [Email] nvarchar(256) NULL,
          [NormalizedEmail] nvarchar(256) NULL,
          [EmailConfirmed] bit NOT NULL,
          [PasswordHash] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [SecurityStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [PhoneNumber] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [PhoneNumberConfirmed] bit NOT NULL,
          [TwoFactorEnabled] bit NOT NULL,
          [LockoutEnd] datetimeoffset NULL,
          [LockoutEnabled] bit NOT NULL,
          [AccessFailedCount] int NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      );
Failed executing DbCommand (21ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [AspNetUsers] (
    [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [Email] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] bit NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] bit NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] bit NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd] datetimeoffset NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] bit NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);


    System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (1722): The RPC server is unavailable.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite(String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID, UInt16 category, EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[] rawData, String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance, Byte[] data, Object[] values)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance, Object[] values)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.WindowsEventLog.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.WriteMessage(String message, EventLogEntryType eventLogEntryType, Int32 eventId)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.<Log>g__LoggerLog|12_0[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, ILogger logger, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter, List`1& exceptions, TState& state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.ThrowLoggingError(List`1 exceptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`6.<Define>b__0(ILogger logger, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.EventDefinition`6.Log[TLoggerCategory](IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, WarningBehavior warningBehavior, TParam1 arg1, TParam2 arg2, TParam3 arg3, TParam4 arg4, TParam5 arg5, TParam6 arg6)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalLoggerExtensions.LogCommandError(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, DbCommand command, TimeSpan duration, EventDefinition`6 definition)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalLoggerExtensions.CommandError(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommand command, DbContext context, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, Guid commandId, Guid connectionId, Exception exception, DateTimeOffset startTime, TimeSpan duration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Cannot open log for source '.NET Runtime'. You may not have write access.)
```

When I check my mssql server I see a new db created as per the name I gave in appsettinngs.json but only with 1 table - efmigrationhistory.

Why such? What mistake did I make? What needs to be done to get the migration going and create the full database with aspnet identity? Please suggest the correction;
Some help needed.

Comment: Errors shown when using update-databse are usually more longer than what you have sent. Please provide the full error message (Usually the part starting with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException).

Comment: hey @MDZand please check the exception details block I have added farther details ..

Comment: This "The RPC server is unavailable" is the problem. Check your connection string and the accepted answer from this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bd6ad7f-eed1-4f88-8394-7aabf5ec5cb7/rpc-server-is-unavailable-0x800706ba-while-updating-password-for-user-in-active-directory?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: @HenrykBudzinski    hi,  the connectionstring is okay, otherwise the database wouldn't be created with the 1 table in it when I run update-database;
 
looking into the RPC issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue.
I ran the query

select @@version

and found that I was running version 2005 of the database engine which does not have the data type datetimeoffset.

I went through the installation process of Sql Server 2019.
And then ran the code migrations of my project allover again. It completed just fine! No issues whatsoever anymore in doing code-migrations,

Answer (score 0):

Does running visual studio as administrator solve or changes the error?

Comment: what? let me check ...    @MDZand;

Comment: no, it doesn't. Error and other associated stuff that I got originally, remain the  same.

Comment: Oh! I should have leaved just a comment not an answer! Excuse me. Anyway, the error does not show the real problem. It just says that it can not write event log which is usually access permission problem. I have faced same error in Asp.Net on IIS but never in VS.

Comment: should I create the whole project from scratch[as opposed to doing the migrations from the middle] and then apply the migrations? Do you think it will make a difference? Cuz the project I have now, as it stands was created with VS running as normal user.....

Comment: I do not think that might help. Try adding new user to the computer and testing with that. Also try reinstalling .Net SDK

Comment: Also found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66574101/an-error-occurred-while-writing-to-loggers-cannot-open-log-for-source-net. Exactly the same error.
Although no solution is provided but may be you can contact the initiator. I am assuming that you have checked that the Windows Log Service is running

Comment: nope; nothing works. started windows log service and event viewer from Administrative Tools>Services . makes no difference. Error remains.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logger configured which writes to Windows Event log. The account you are running your migrations under does not have access to writing logs, which is why the whole operation is failing.

Either grant it the necessary permissions or don't write to event log.

P.S.: Since your application is likely cross-platform otherwise, I question the wisdom of writing to Windows specific logs.

Comment: hi @TanveerBadar   how do I do that? I mean stop writing to the windows event log ? I am bit confused because in my StartUp.cs there's no ILogger related initialization or implementations .... So where from do I stop the writing? Kindly suggest